# Help construst a measurable set in $\mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0＜\theta＜1$. Construct a measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\lambda(E\cap (0,r))}{r}＝\theta$

I'm considering that since $\lambda(E\cap (0,r))$ is a continuous fuction of r. If we can choose E to let it be a polygonal with the form of
$\theta r＜\lambda(E\cap (0,r))＜\theta r+o(r)$ then the conclusion is obvious. But it seems that I can't construct a E with a form of $\bigcup[a_n,b_n]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you construct $E$ so that
$$\lambda\left(E\cap\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac\theta{n(n+1)},$$
then for $\frac1{n+1}\le r\le\frac1n$ you will have
$$\frac n{n+1}\cdot\theta\le\frac{\lambda(E\cap(0,r))}r\le\frac{n+1}n\cdot\theta.$$

Comment: In particular, you can take $$E\equiv\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n(n+1)},\frac{n+\theta}{n(n+1)}\right].$$